# Compilation and execution time of C++ vs C source code

Tags: c++, c, performance, compilation, execution-time

I am not sure if this is a valid comparison or a valid statement but over the years I have heard folks claiming that the programs written in C++ generally take a longer time for compilation than the same written in C and that the applications coded in C++ are generally slower at run time than ones written in C.
Is there any truth in these statements?
Apart from reaping the benefits of OOP flexibility that C++ provides, should the above comparison be given a consideration purely from a compilation/execution time perspective?

I hope that this doesn't get closed as too generic or vague, it is just an attempt to know the actual facts about statements I have been hearing over the years from many programmers(C programmers predominantly).

Comment: I reckon a little Google search will give ten thousands of hits on this very topic, including numerous essays and research papers.

Comment: @Lundin: I look up to SO as having a excellent pool of experts giving out valuable advice and recommendations based on their personal and professional experiences. There would be no use of SO if one had to google and read tens and thousands of essays instead of benefiting from experiences of fellow expert programmers.

Comment: The trouble with this question is "the same program in C". The trouble is that naively implementing the same program in C does not give you the same program. The C++ compiler generates a lot more code that you don't actually see that the the "C" programmer should implement to make the programs the same. Thus you should add a third subjective measure to your test. How long does it take to `write` an equivalent C++/C program. Given an non trivial application I would suspect that the difference is significant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll answer one specific part of the question that's pretty objective. C++ code that uses templates is going to be slower to compile than C code. If you don't use templates (which you probably will if you use the standard library) it should be very similar compilation time.

EDIT:
In terms of runtime it's much more subjective. Even though C may be a somewhat lower level language, C++ optimizers are getting really good, and C++ lends itself to more naturally representing real world concepts. If it's easier to represent your requirements in code (as I'd argue in C++) it's often easier to write better (and more performant) code than you would in another language. I don't think there's any objective data showing C or C++ being faster in all possible cases. I would actually suggest picking your language based on project needs and then write it in that language. If things are too slow, profile and proceed with normal performance improvement techniques.

Comment: Yes its understandable in case of templates as compilers needs to generate the specializations.

Comment: Template may also increase runtime in some extreme case due to over inlining (template tends to encourage inlining since all code need to be available in header), and / or due to code size increase (when they are not inlined and the linker is not smart enough to merge function corresponding to different instantiation of the template but generating the same code, think `std::vector< int* >` and `std::vector< float* >`) which can cause more cache miss.

Comment: @Sylvain - How would writing it in C help you with that?

Comment: Well, concerning the inlining, in C, this is generally a decision you have to take. For the code duplication, you will probably define an algorithm or data structure working on opaque type (think `qsort`) or storing `void*` (that can be done in `C++`, but since it is not type safe, it is discouraged).

Comment: @Sylvain - Ah, so using C++ forces me to write better programs? I can live with that! :-)

Answer (score 11):

The relatively runtime speed is a bit hard to predict. At one time, when most people thought of C++ as being all about inheritance, and used virtual functions a *lot* (even when they weren't particularly appropriate), code written in C++ was typically a little bit slower than equivalent C.

With (what most of us would consider) modern C++, the reverse tends to be true: templates give enough more compile-time flexibility that you can frequently produce code that's noticeably faster than any reasonable equivalent in C. In theory you could always avoid that by writing specialized code equivalent to the result of "expanding" a template -- but in reality, doing so is exceedingly rare, and quite expensive.

There is something of a tendency for C++ to be written somewhat more generally as well -- just for example, reading data into `std::string` or `std::vector` (or `std::vector<std::string>`) so the user can enter an arbitrary amount of data without buffer overflow *or* the data simply be truncated at some point. In C it's a *lot* more common to see somebody just code up a fixed-size buffer, and if you enter more than that, it either overflows or truncates. Obviously enough, you pay something for that -- the C++ code typically ends up using dynamic allocation (`new`), which is typically slower than just defining an array. OTOH, if you write C to accomplish the same thing, you end up writing a lot of extra code, and it typically runs about the same speed as the C++ version.

In other words, it's pretty easy to write C that's noticeably faster for things like benchmarks and single-use utilities, but the speed advantage evaporates in real code that has to be robust. In the latter case, about the best you can usually hope for is that the C code is equivalent to a C++ version, and in all honesty doing even that well is *fairly* unusual (at least IME).

Comparing compilation speed is no easier. On one hand, it's absolutely true that templates can be slow -- at least with most compilers, instantiating templates is quite expensive. On a line-for-line basis, there's no question that C will almost always be faster than anything in C++ that uses templates much. The problem with that is that a line-for-line comparison rarely makes much sense -- 10 lines of C++ may easily be equivalent to hundreds or even thousands of lines of C. As long as you look *only* at compile time (not development time), the balance probably favors C anyway, but certainly *not* by nearly as dramatic a margin as might initially seem to be the case. This also depends heavily on the compiler: just for example, clang does a *lot* better than gcc in this respect (and gcc has improved a lot in the last few years too).

Answer (score 7):

The run time of C++ versus C would suffer only if you use certain C++-specific features. Exceptions and virtual function calls add to run time compared to returning error code and direct calls. On the other hand, if you find yourself using function pointers in C (as, say, GTK does) you are already paying at least some of the price for virtual functions. And checking error code after each function return will consume time too - you don't do it when you use exceptions.

On the other hand, inlining and templates in C++ may allow you to do a lot of work compile-time - work that C defers to run time. In some cases, C++ may end up faster than C.

Comment: If used only when appropriate, exceptions will generally result
in (very slightly) faster code than return codes.

Answer (score 6):

If you compile the same code as C and C++, there should be no difference.

If you let the compiler do the job for you, like expanding templates, that will take some time. If you do the same in C, with cut-and-paste or some intricate macros, it will take up **your** time instead.

In some cases, inline expansion of templates will actually result in code that is more specialized and runs **faster** than the equivalent C code. Like here:

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/new_learning.pdf

Or this report showing that many C++ features have no runtime cost:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/TR18015.pdf

Comment: The trouble is "The Same Code". To write the same code in C that is executed by a C++ program requires the engineer to write significantly more C source code (because of the extra features of the language). So the "Same Code" test is very subjective when just looking at a non trivial program.

Comment: @Loki Astari: Old comment, I know, but Bo probably meant literally the same code - e.g. the same files, once compiled as c++ by g++ and once by as c by gcc (of course that is only possible if it is written in the intersection of c and c++).

Comment: @MikeMB: Then you are only writing C. Sure if you write C and compile it with g++ and gcc then you will get the same code. But it makes the question not interesting at all if you look at that way.

Comment: @Loki: Well, it's only a very small part of the answer and I didn't say anything about the scope of the question anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Although its an old question I'd like to add my 5cents here, as I'm probably not the only one who finds this question via a search engine.

I can't comment on compilation speed but on execution speed:

To the best of my knowledge, there is only one feature in c++ that costs performance, even if you don't use it. This feature are the c++ exceptions, because they prevent a few compiler optimizations (that is the reason, why `noexcept` was introduced in c++11). However, if you use some kind of error checking mechanism, then exceptions are probably more efficient than the combination of return value checking and a lot `if else` statements. This is especially true, if you have to escalate an error up the stack.

Anyway, if you turn off exceptions during compilation, c++ introduces no overhead, except in places where you deliberately use the associated features (e.g. you dont't have to pay for polymorphism if you don't use virtual functions), whereas most features introduce no runtime overhead at all (overloading, templates, namespaces a.s.o.). 
On the other hand, most forms of generic code will be much faster in c++ than the equivalent in c, because c++ provides the built-in mechanisms (templates and classes) to do this. A typical example is c's qsort vs c++'s std::sort. The c++ version is usually much faster, because inside sort, the used comparator function is known at compile time, which at least saves a call through a function lookup and in the best case allows a lot of additional compiler optimizations.

That being said, the "problem" with c++ is that it's easy to hide complexity from the user such that seemingly innocent code might be much slower than expected. This is mainly due to operator overloading, polymorphism and constructors/destructors, but even a simple call to a member function hides the passed `this`-pointer which also isn't a NOP. 
Considering operator overloading: When you see a `*` in c, you know this is (on most architectures) a single, cheap assembler instruction, in c++ on the other hand it can be a complex function call (think about matrix multiplication). That doesn't mean, you could implement the same functionality in c any faster but in c++ you don't directly see that this might be an expensive operation. 
Destructors are a similar case: In "modern" c++, you will hardly see any explicit destructions via delete but any local variable that goes out of scope might potentially trigger an expensive call to a (virtual) destructor without a single line of code indicating this (ignoring `}` of course). 
And finally, some people (especially coming from Java) tend to write complex class hierarchies with lots of virtual functions, where each call to such a function is a hidden indirect function call which is difficult or impossible to optimize.
So while hiding complexity from the programmer is in general a good thing it sometimes has an adverse effect on runtime, if the programmer is not aware of the costs of these "easy to use" constructs.

As a summary I would say, that c++ makes it easier for inexperienced programmers to write slow code (because they don't directly see inefficiencies in a program). But c++ also allows good programmers to write "good", correct and fast code faster than with c - which gives them more time to think about optimizations when they really are necessary.

P.S.:
Two things I haven't mentioned (probably among others that I simply forgot) are c++'s ability for complex compile time computations (thanks to templates and constexpr) and c's restrict keyword. This is because didn't use either of them in time critical programs yet and so I can't comment on their general usefulness and the real world performance benefit.

Answer (score -1):

C applications are faster to compile and execute than C++ applications.

C++ applications are generally slower at runtime, and are much slower to compile than C programs.

Look at these links:

- [C vs C++ (a)](http://unthought.net/c++/c_vs_c++.html)
- [C vs C++ (b)](http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/basics/comparingcppandcperformance.htm)
- [Efficient C/C++](http://embeddedgurus.com/stack-overflow/category/efficient-cc/)
- [C++ Compile Time and RunTime Performance](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/CC_perf/content.html)

Comment: I find it hard to believe that "C++ applications are generally slower at runtime". Do you have any evidence for this statement?

Comment: Some of those articles are 5-10 years old. Hardly relevant anymore.

Comment: @Bo Why? The latest C standard was released 12 years ago and the latest C++ standard was released 8 years ago. I'm fairly certain there have not been any revolutionary changes in general compiler efficiency since then.

Comment: @Lundin - You don't need a revolution if you have 10 years to work on the optimizer. VC2010 easily beats VC2002, and gcc 4.5 optimizes a lot better than gcc 3.x

Comment: @Lundin: Differences in optimization depend less on the compiler or standard, and more on how the code is written. 10 years ago, most C++ code used lots of inheritance and virtual functions. Now, most C++ code depends much more heavily on templates, and uses virtual functions minimally if at all. That lets enough more happen at compile time that C++ usually ends up at least a little faster than C.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin Most C++ code today makes extensive use of
templates.  Inheritance and templates serve two very different
purposes, and most modern C++ uses both.  The most important
difference with regards to performance is that C++ supports
better encapsulation, and better encapsulation leads to better
performance, since when the profiler designates the hot spots,
you can easily change the implementation without rewriting the
entire application.

Comment: @Jame Kanze: Yes -- I didn't mean to imply that inheritance was no longer used, only that at one time it was often used even when it wasn't needed, which is much less often the case anymore.

Comment: you should really update your answers when they're time relevant.